# Can't update inputs in shiny app with observeEvent and eventReactive

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, shiny-server

I have a database which is more or less like this one I created for my reprex:

```
structure(list(año = c("2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", "2020", 
"2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", 
"2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021"), opciones = c("L1", "L1", "L1", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L3", 
"L3", "L3", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LB", "LB", "LB", "LC", "LC", "LC", 
"L1", "L1", "L1", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L3", "L3", "L3", "LA", "LA", 
"LA", "LB", "LB", "LB", "LC", "LC", "LC", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L2", 
"L2", "L2", "L3", "L3", "L3", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LB", "LB", "LB", 
"LC", "LC", "LC"), lugar = c("EXT", "INT", "LOC", "NOM", "KHA", 
"POC", "TMO", "MCR", "GNR", "APV", "HOT", "ROR", "GRU", "BOY", 
"POK", "NOT", "LOX", "TAK", "EXT", "INT", "LOC", "NOM", "KHA", 
"POC", "TMO", "MCR", "GNR", "APV", "HOT", "ROR", "GRU", "BOY", 
"POK", "NOT", "LOX", "TAK", "EXT", "INT", "LOC", "NOM", "KHA", 
"POC", "TMO", "MCR", "GNR", "APV", "HOT", "ROR", "GRU", "BOY", 
"POK", "NOT", "LOX", "TAK"), numeros = c(4011L, 18564L, 24325L, 
9798L, 18621L, 11165L, 6071L, 23466L, 22472L, 23990L, 3980L, 
2976L, 24142L, 3140L, 20317L, 11884L, 9427L, 20704L, 609L, 23428L, 
19853L, 10450L, 577L, 14153L, 4757L, 6393L, 18461L, 1988L, 20044L, 
8371L, 21371L, 12312L, 17368L, 16045L, 11492L, 7903L, 21409L, 
12547L, 19926L, 17857L, 6728L, 5584L, 14837L, 10269L, 20168L, 
13092L, 22233L, 20663L, 11975L, 14672L, 19389L, 7329L, 14062L, 
167L), mes = c("Agosto", "Julio", "Agosto", "Febrero", "Julio", 
"Agosto", "Mayo", "Noviembre", "Abril", "Diciembre", "Julio", 
"Febrero", "Mayo", "Octubre", "Septiembre", "Febrero", "Enero", 
"Febrero", "Noviembre", "Julio", "Septiembre", "Marzo", "Diciembre", 
"Octubre", "Enero", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Abril", "Julio", 
"Enero", "Febrero", "Febrero", "Abril", "Septiembre", "Agosto", 
"Septiembre", "Abril", "Septiembre", "Abril", "Febrero", "Marzo", 
"Febrero", "Abril", "Noviembre", "Noviembre", "Septiembre", "Abril", 
"Enero", "Marzo", "Julio", "Mayo", "Febrero", "Febrero", "Agosto"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -54L))
```

Final result for my app will be some bar plot which shows "numeros" for some "año", "mes", "opcion" and "lugar" selected. What I specifically want for this is that "Lugar" gets updated when  "Opción" is selected. I went through many documentation and I used both `eventReactive()` and `observEvent()` but I'm getting this error:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6373
Warning: Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
  [No stack trace available]
```

I don't know if I need to use `eventReactive()` and `observEvent()` linked to my database (instead lists and vectors) for "Lugar" to get updated when "Opción" changes or there's simply something I'm missing in my code (code below).

```
# Options for tabs

años <- c("2019", "2020", "2021")

meses <- c("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Julio",
           "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre")

opciones <- c("L1","L2","L3","LA","LB","LC")

lugar <- list(L1=c("EXT","INT","LOC"), L2=c("NOM","KHA","POC"),
    L3= c("TMO", "MCR", "GNR"), LA=c("APV", "HOT", "ROR"),
    LB= c("GRU", "BOY", "POK"), LC=c("NOT", "LOX", "TAK"))

## App 

test_lugar <- tabPanel(
  titlePanel= "Test", 
  titlePanel(h5("Test")),
  sidebarLayout(    
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("año", "Año", choices=años,
                  selected= "2019"), 
      selectInput("mes", "Mes", choices=meses,
                  selected="Enero", multiple=TRUE),
      selectInput("opcion", "Opción",
                  choices=opciones, selected="L1"),
      selectInput("lugar", "Lugar", c()), multiple=TRUE), 
    mainPanel(  
      plotlyOutput("afluencia_estaciones", height = "400px", width="1000px")
    )
  )
)


ui <- navbarPage(title = h5(strong("XXXX")),
                 theme = shinytheme("paper"),
                 test_lugar)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  seleccionar_opcion_lugar <- eventReactive(input$opcion, {
    get("lugar")[[input$opcion]]
  })
  
  lugar_seleccionado <- observeEvent(input$opcion, {
    req(seleccionar_opcion_lugar())
    choices <- unlist(seleccionar_opcion_lugar)
    updateSelectInput(session,"lugar", choices=choices, 
                      selected=choices[1])
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)    

    # Then some barplot here

}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

Any advice or help will be much appreciated

Comment: You are updating object with ID `estacion`, where is that `SelectInput` defined?

Comment: @YBS Thanks for your observation. I made an edition. I copied & pasted from my original app design because my base data.frame is very huge and has some sensitive data. Hope this time makes a little sense.

Comment: Try `choices <- unlist(seleccionar_opcion_lugar())`.  You were missing `()` when you called the reactive object.

Comment: That works but partially. I can't select multiple values for "Lugar", argument multiple=TRUE inside updateSelectInput() is not accepted.

Comment: It works for me.  I will post the code.

Comment: That may be due to closing the bracket too early in the last selectInput.  You had `c())`.  So, `multiple=TRUE` was not part of the last `selectInput`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
# Options for tabs

años <- c("2019", "2020", "2021")

meses <- c("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Juno", "Julio",
           "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre")

opciones <- c("L1","L2","L3","LA","LB","LC")

lugar <- list(L1=c("EXT","INT","LOC"), L2=c("NOM","KHA","POC"),
              L3= c("TMO", "MCR", "GNR"), LA=c("APV", "HOT", "ROR"),
              LB= c("GRU", "BOY", "POK"), LC=c("NOT", "LOX", "TAK"))

## App 

test_lugar <- tabPanel(
  titlePanel= "Test", 
  titlePanel(h5("Test")),
  sidebarLayout(    
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("año", "Año", choices=años,
                  selected= "2019"), 
      selectInput("mes", "Mes", choices=meses,
                  selected="Enero", multiple=TRUE),
      selectInput("opcion", "Opción",
                  choices=opciones, selected="L1"),
      selectInput("lugar", "Lugar", c(), multiple=TRUE) 
      ), 
    mainPanel(  
      #plotlyOutput("afluencia_estaciones", height = "400px", width="1000px")
    )
  )
)


ui <- navbarPage(title = h5(strong("XXXX")),
                 theme = shinytheme("paper"),
                 test_lugar)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  seleccionar_opcion_lugar <- eventReactive(input$opcion, {
    get("lugar")[[input$opcion]]
  })
  
  observe({print(seleccionar_opcion_lugar())})
  
  #lugar_seleccionado <- 
  observeEvent(input$opcion, {
    req(seleccionar_opcion_lugar())
    choices <- unlist(seleccionar_opcion_lugar())
    updateSelectInput(session,"lugar", choices=choices,
                      selected=choices[1])
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  # Then some barplot here
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

[image: output]