# Problems with shiny: Graph doesn't show when inputs are updated (plus some error)

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, dashboard

As a continuation of my previous problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69621049/cant-update-inputs-in-shiny-app-with-observeevent-and-eventreactive?), now I'm stuck with my graph.I really thought it would be so simple because my inputs are correctly updated but i'm receiving this error when the browser opens to display the app:

```
Error: no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "shiny.tag"
```

I'm really confused and exhausted and I just can't see where the problem is: in the code that generates the database for the graph (I used many `dplyr::filter` because I thought the problem was there but that makes no difference) or the code for the graph itself or in both.

I appreciate all your feedback and comments.

Below is all you need to replicate:

Dummy database:

```
x <-   structure(list(año = c("2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
    "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
    "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", "2020", 
    "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", 
    "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2021", 
    "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
    "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
    "2021"), opciones = c("L1", "L1", "L1", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L3", 
    "L3", "L3", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LB", "LB", "LB", "LC", "LC", "LC", 
    "L1", "L1", "L1", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L3", "L3", "L3", "LA", "LA", 
    "LA", "LB", "LB", "LB", "LC", "LC", "LC", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L2", 
    "L2", "L2", "L3", "L3", "L3", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LB", "LB", "LB", 
    "LC", "LC", "LC"), lugar = c("EXT", "INT", "LOC", "NOM", "KHA", 
    "POC", "TMO", "MCR", "GNR", "APV", "HOT", "ROR", "GRU", "BOY", 
    "POK", "NOT", "LOX", "TAK", "EXT", "INT", "LOC", "NOM", "KHA", 
    "POC", "TMO", "MCR", "GNR", "APV", "HOT", "ROR", "GRU", "BOY", 
    "POK", "NOT", "LOX", "TAK", "EXT", "INT", "LOC", "NOM", "KHA", 
    "POC", "TMO", "MCR", "GNR", "APV", "HOT", "ROR", "GRU", "BOY", 
    "POK", "NOT", "LOX", "TAK"), numeros = c(4011L, 18564L, 24325L, 
    9798L, 18621L, 11165L, 6071L, 23466L, 22472L, 23990L, 3980L, 
    2976L, 24142L, 3140L, 20317L, 11884L, 9427L, 20704L, 609L, 23428L, 
    19853L, 10450L, 577L, 14153L, 4757L, 6393L, 18461L, 1988L, 20044L, 
    8371L, 21371L, 12312L, 17368L, 16045L, 11492L, 7903L, 21409L, 
    12547L, 19926L, 17857L, 6728L, 5584L, 14837L, 10269L, 20168L, 
    13092L, 22233L, 20663L, 11975L, 14672L, 19389L, 7329L, 14062L, 
    167L), mes = c("Agosto", "Julio", "Agosto", "Febrero", "Julio", 
    "Agosto", "Mayo", "Noviembre", "Abril", "Diciembre", "Julio", 
    "Febrero", "Mayo", "Octubre", "Septiembre", "Febrero", "Enero", 
    "Febrero", "Noviembre", "Julio", "Septiembre", "Marzo", "Diciembre", 
    "Octubre", "Enero", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Abril", "Julio", 
    "Enero", "Febrero", "Febrero", "Abril", "Septiembre", "Agosto", 
    "Septiembre", "Abril", "Septiembre", "Abril", "Febrero", "Marzo", 
    "Febrero", "Abril", "Noviembre", "Noviembre", "Septiembre", "Abril", 
    "Enero", "Marzo", "Julio", "Mayo", "Febrero", "Febrero", "Agosto"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -54L))
```

The code for the app:

```
# Options for tabs

años <- c("2019", "2020", "2021")

meses <- c("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Juno", "Julio",
           "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre")

opciones <- c("L1","L2","L3","LA","LB","LC")

lugar <- list(L1=c("EXT","INT","LOC"), L2=c("NOM","KHA","POC"),
              L3= c("TMO", "MCR", "GNR"), LA=c("APV", "HOT", "ROR"),
              LB= c("GRU", "BOY", "POK"), LC=c("NOT", "LOX", "TAK"))

## App 

test_lugar <- tabPanel(
  titlePanel= "Test", 
  titlePanel(h5("Test")),
  sidebarLayout(    
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("año", "Año", choices=años,
                  selected= "2019"), 
      selectInput("mes", "Mes", choices=meses,
                  selected="Enero", multiple=TRUE),
      selectInput("opcion", "Opción",
                  choices=opciones, selected="L1"),
      selectInput("lugar", "Lugar", c(), multiple=TRUE) 
      ), 
    mainPanel(  
      #plotlyOutput("afluencia_lugar", height = "400px", width="1000px")
    )
  )
)


ui <- navbarPage(title = h5(strong("XXXX")),
                 theme = shinytheme("paper"),
                 test_lugar)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  seleccionar_opcion_lugar <- eventReactive(input$opcion, {
    get("lugar")[[input$opcion]]
  })
  
  observe({print(seleccionar_opcion_lugar())})
  
  lugar_seleccionado <- 
  observeEvent(input$opcion, {
    req(seleccionar_opcion_lugar())
    choices <- unlist(seleccionar_opcion_lugar())
    updateSelectInput(session,"lugar", choices=choices,
                      selected=choices[1])
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
 
### CODE FOR THE GRAPH 


lugar_mensual <- reactive({
    x%>%  
      dplyr::filter(año==input$año)%>%
        dplyr::filter(mes%in%input$mes)%>%
        dplyr::filter(opcion==input$opcion)%>%
        dplyr::filter(lugar%in%input$lugar())
        })
  
 
  output$afluencia_lugar <- renderPlotly({
   ggplot(data= lugar_mensual(), 
            aes(x=mes, y=numeros)) +
            labs(x="Fecha", y="Afluencia")+
            geom_col() +
            theme_minimal() +
            facet_wrap(~input$lugar)
 })



  
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few issues. There was a typo, and you don't need `lugar_seleccionado <-` as you don't need to assign `observeEvent`.  Also, you need to use `plotly` object in `renderPlotly`, just convert your `ggplot` object by using `ggplotly`.
Lastly, in the `facet_wrap()`, you should use the variables present in the dataframe (say, `lugar`) which has already used the user input variable `input$lugar` to subset the required info.  Try this

```
  # Options for tabs

  años <- c("2019", "2020", "2021")

  meses <- c("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Juno", "Julio",
             "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre")

  opciones <- c("L1","L2","L3","LA","LB","LC")

  lugar <- list(L1=c("EXT","INT","LOC"), L2=c("NOM","KHA","POC"),
                L3= c("TMO", "MCR", "GNR"), LA=c("APV", "HOT", "ROR"),
                LB= c("GRU", "BOY", "POK"), LC=c("NOT", "LOX", "TAK"))

  ## App

  test_lugar <- tabPanel(
    titlePanel= "Test",
    titlePanel(h5("Test")),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("año", "Año", choices=años,
                    selected= "2019"),
        selectInput("mes", "Mes", choices=meses,
                    selected="Enero", multiple=TRUE),
        selectInput("opcion", "Opción",
                    choices=opciones, selected="L1"),
        selectInput("lugar", "Lugar", c(), multiple=TRUE)
      ),
      mainPanel(  DTOutput("t1"),
        plotlyOutput("afluencia_lugar", height = "400px")
      )
    )
  )


  ui <- navbarPage(title = h5(strong("XXXX")),
                   theme = shinytheme("paper"),
                   test_lugar)

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    seleccionar_opcion_lugar <- eventReactive(input$opcion, {
      get("lugar")[[input$opcion]]
    })

    observe({print(as.character(input$año))})

    ## lugar_seleccionado <-
      observeEvent(input$opcion, {
        req(seleccionar_opcion_lugar())
        choices <- unlist(seleccionar_opcion_lugar())
        updateSelectInput(session,"lugar", choices=choices, selected=choices[1])
      }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

    ### CODE FOR THE GRAPH

    lugar_mensual <- reactive({
      x %>%
        dplyr::filter(año %in% input$año)%>%
        dplyr::filter(mes %in% input$mes)%>%
        dplyr::filter(opciones %in% input$opcion)%>%
        dplyr::filter(lugar %in% input$lugar )
    })

    output$t1 <- renderDT(lugar_mensual())
    output$afluencia_lugar <- renderPlotly({
      p <- ggplot(data= lugar_mensual(),
             aes(x=mes, y=numeros)) +
        geom_col() +
        labs(x="Fecha", y="Afluencia")+
        theme_minimal() +
        facet_wrap(~lugar)
      ggplotly(p)
    })

  }

  shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

[image: output]

Comment: I tried your solution in my original app but it still shows the error. Is it possible that I can reach you personally?

Comment: Sure you can.  You have sparse data (in the sample data), so it will show blank plot in many choices.  Does this MRE (as is) work for you?

Comment: Thank you, man. I'll send you all the required BD and scripts. I'll explain you in the e-mail. Thank you so much.

Comment: Done, man. I sent you an e-mail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera, please try the updated code.

Comment: I implemented your solution and worked perfectly. I wrote you again with an additional request (hope this is the last one). Thank you!